# Closing ContextMenu by left MouseClick

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a button that opens a ContextMenu after I click on it.

```
   private void menuButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {

        ((Button)sender).ContextMenu.PlacementTarget = sender as Button;
        ((Button)sender).ContextMenu.Placement = System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.PlacementMode.Bottom;
        ((Button)sender).ContextMenu.IsOpen = true;

    }
```

When I click on the button the Menu opens as I want. However, when I click again the menu seems to close and re-open very fast. This, makes it sound like everytime I click with the mouse on the menu button, the menu re-opens and never closes.

I tried:

```
((Button)sender).ContextMenu.IsOpen = !((Button)sender).ContextMenu.IsOpen;
```

The value of IsOpen becomes false when I press by mouse. Actually I notice that the menu closes every time I click by mouse anywhere on the page(including the button itself). Thus, the IsOpen becomes false.

Is there a clean way of making the mouse click Open and Close the Menu?Is ContextMenu implemented to close if I left-click the mouse?

Thank you

Comment: That is just the way a context menu works.  *Any* click will make it close, whether you click on a menu item or anywhere else.  That it does not swallow a click on the button is not so pretty, WPF fumbles the standard behavior of controls occasionally.  Albeit that it isn't going to stump the user much when he learns that clicking the button always produces the menu.

Comment: Use a Popup instead of a ContextMenu if you want to be able open/close it explicitly.